# compare day with getDay from a Date object in a JSON API output

Tags: javascript

I am working with some data being outputted from a JSON API. I have a loop that is pulling bits and pieces from the API and I would like to compare the day in a date object.  I am not 100% sure if the date in the output is an object but it looks like this, example: `2021-09-27T02:15:00-07:00`.

What I am trying to compare is the day which is **27** in the above example and once the day in the look changes to **28** then I want to do something.

I do have the index in my loop so I think my best bet is compare with the previous day in the last index with `i - 1`, but it doesn't look I can compare the date value like this because this compares the whole date value including the time `02:15:00`, so this cannot be accurate:

```
if (data[i].PresentationDate !== data[i - 1].PresentationDate)
```

and it doesn't look I can `getDay()` from PresentationDate like this:

```
if (data[i].PresentationDate.getDay() == data[i - 1].PresentationDate.getDay()) {...}
```

when I try to do so then I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: data[i].PresentationDate.getDay is not a function.

What am I doing wrong and what's the best and most accurate way to get the Day in this loop and compare it with the previous index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data[i].PresentationDate` is a `String` (as your error somewhat alludes to), parse it to a `Date` object first, then compare the year/month/day and take the action you need based on the outcome:

```
var currentDate = new Date(data[i].PresentationDate);
var prevDate = new Date(data[i-1].PresentationDate);

if (currentDate.getDay() == prevDate.getDay() && currentDate.getMonth() == prevDate.getMonth() && currentDate.getYear() == prevDate.getYear()) {
    // same day
} else {
    // different day
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I see what you umean by string vs Date object. I am getting the correct result back when I console.log but the comparison is not working the way I was expecting. I'll test more tomorrow but this is great, thanks again for the insight.